# Looping through Images When Running HTML Script

Tags: html, image, loops

Does anyone have a code that can read through a list of URLs of images contained in an XML file and loop through them when running the HTML script?  The time element is how many seconds it waits until it goes to the next one.  The given url does not actually work.   Here is an example of what the xml file looks like:

```
<list>
    <url>
        <link>
        http:blahblahblah.com/file/image01.jpg
        </link>
        <time>6</time>
    </url>
</list>
```

Comment: In HTML its not possible, are you using PHP or javaScript?

Comment: Of course we thought `http:blahblahblah.com/file/image01.jpg` was a working image address :D

Comment: Im running an html scrip containing javascript

@AhmedHabib

Answer (score 0):

you can likely read the file in using javascript

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript

and then append to an HTML element using appendChild

[Javascript - Append HTML to container element without innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/javascript-append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml)

coupled with a setTimeout based on the value of your  field!