# How to append script, link, and meta tags onto head using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I got output like below, how to append whole into the head tag using JavaScript?

```
<meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/template.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/templatee.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        BODY {background: #00ff00;color: rgb(0,0,255);}
    ]]>
</style>
```

Comment: Notice, that appending some `meta` tags after the head has been parsed is not useful, they are simply ignored.

Comment: I need all into head tag

Comment: Where is this output you got coming from?

Comment: The title of your question says you're appending a script tag, but your example contains no script tag.

Comment: `head` is guaranteed to be loaded and parsed before `body`, forking `head` afterwards breaks the default behavior. So, basicly you shouldn't do this. If you need dynamic `head`, create it on server-side. Rather this sounds like an XY-problem, what is the actual purpose of re-building the `head`?

Comment: yeah...  i have added script dynamic using php. i have followed order first for meta,then title and link,script... In this way i have planned to append this into to head

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Append HTML to container element without innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/javascript-append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
document.querySelector('head').innerHTML = "insert your code here"
```

Comment: Not working.  I hava all in text which contain may be link,script,title,meta tag, i cound not append all into head tag

Comment: Why not just `document.head`? Anyway, this will obliterate whatever content the `head` element used to contain.