# clicking the button again making the field reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When ever i click the add button it makes the previous value disappear.
Example if i click add first time and enter the values in the first input boxes. and the click the add button it is making the previous values disappear from the input boxes

```js
  function addInput(event) {
    var field =
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_text" placeholder="Selected Text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for selected text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_text" placeholder="UnSelected Text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for unselected text"></div>'
    document.getElementById('inputField').innerHTML += field;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left" onclick="addInput(event)">Add</a>
</div>
<div id="inputField" style="background-color:#eceff1;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding elements to innerHTML reloads the entire element beforehand. That's why the values get reset.

You could try using the [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) function. Then this line

```
document.getElementById('inputField').innerHTML += field;
```

will become this

```
document.getElementById('inputField').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', field);
```

Snippet :

```js
  function addInput(event) {
    var field =
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_text" placeholder="Selected Text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for selected text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_text" placeholder="UnSelected Text"></div>' +
      '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for unselected text"></div>'
    document.getElementById('inputField').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', field);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left" onclick="addInput(event)">Add</a>
</div>
<div id="inputField" style="background-color:#eceff1;">
</div>
```

Source : [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851500/6385427)

Answer (score 1):

I totally converted the program to **jquery** and its working..

```
 $("#link").click(function() {
   var field =
     '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_text" placeholder="Selected Text"></div>' +
     '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="selected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for selected text"></div>' +
     '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_text" placeholder="UnSelected Text"></div>' +
     '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unselected_route_url" placeholder="Route Url for unselected text"></div>';
   $('#inputField').append(field);
   event.preventDefault();

 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="link">Add</a>
</div>
<div id="inputField" style="background-color:#eceff1;">
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pfr5g77a/)