# Html not working on css tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

My css 3 tooltip (created folowing [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)) is showing this :

> `Name </br> Description`

instead of

> `Name`
>   `Description`

The html code used to create the tooltip has been made by my javascript script :

```
var DivItem = document.createElement("div");
var span = document.createElement("span");
var spanText = document.createTextNode(Name + "<br>" + Description;

span.appendChild(spanText);
span.className = "TooltipText";

DivItem.appendChild(span);
DivItem.className = "Tooltip";

MainDiv.appendChild(DivItem);
```

I need to use the javascript code here beacause i make an list of items (got from a json), and i need to have a tooltip to show more informations on the hovered item.

Comment: Use `span.innerHTML`

Comment: And your code won't run, you forgot to close the paranthesis in line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createTextNode`, unsurprisingly, creates a text node.

If you want a br element, you need to create an element.

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Name));
span.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Description));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `createTextNode` you can use:

```
span.innerHTML = `${Name}<br>${Description}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add with innerHTML of created element.You can achieve that [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/javascript-append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml)

```
var DivItem = document.createElement("div");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML =Name + "<br>" + Description;
    span.className = "TooltipText";

    DivItem.appendChild(span);
    DivItem.className = "Tooltip";

    MainDiv.appendChild(DivItem);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can not use text node to render html.instead you can use innerHTML