# Create a bootstrap button inside cell columns of a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, bootstrap-4

i want to put this button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab btn-icon btn-round">
```

Inside the column called "Details"

[image]

But i dont know how, this is my code

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById('ticker_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var tickerArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();
        newRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["ticker"]));
        newRow.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["fund"]));
        newRow.insertCell(2).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["index_tracked"]));
        newRow.insertCell(3).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["assetclass"]));
     }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to repeat btn in each row. you can try using innerhtml.     newRow.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab btn-icon btn-round">";

Comment: Wow, it was more simple that i thought, thanks!! you saved my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a text note, you could use the `insertAdjacentHTML` to add data before the end :

```js
var tableRef = document.getElementById('ticker_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var tickerArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();  newRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["ticker"]));
    newRow.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["fund"]));
    newRow.insertCell(2).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["index_tracked"]));
    newRow.insertCell(3).appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]["assetclass"]));
    newRow.insertCell(4).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab btn-icon btn-round">');
 }
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851500/5784924) for more informations about the `insertAdjacentHTML` function