# How to make the code display all the products saved in cartData in the shopping cart but not only the last product?

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

I think the solution could modifying the last line `cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML` to be increasingly repeatable with the loop based on the number of the products in the cartData (based on its length). Could any one help me with this?

```
                for (var i = 0; i<cartData.length; i++) {
                    this["cartData"+i]=cartData[i]
                

                    let cartHTML = `
                    <tr class="cart-row">
                        <td><a href="#" type="button" class="cart-remove-button"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                        <td><img src="${cartData[i][2]}" alt=""></td>
                        <td>${cartData[i][0]}</td>
                        <td class="cart-price">DZD ${cartData[i][1]}</td>
                        <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1"></td>
                        <td class="cart-sub-total">DZD ${cartData[i][1]}</td>
                    </tr>`;
                    //console.log(i)
                    **cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML**
}
```

The line `cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML` have to be increasingly repeatable with the loop based on the number of the products in the cartData (based on its length).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append HTML to container element without innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml)

Comment: The term you're looking for is *append*  (or *insert*)

Answer (score 1):

With each iteration of the loop you're rewriting the cartItems innerHTML instead of adding to it.

Instead of doing this:

`cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML`

You should instead do this:

`cartItems.innerHTML = cartItems.innerHTML + cartHTML`

Which you could rewrite as:

`cartItems.innerHTML += cartHTML`

Note, still, that it would probably be better to create the the HTML of the table in it's entirety and append it to the page in one go. Why? Because each time you add stuff to the page you force the browser to do a bunch of "expensive" calculations to know how to rerender the page with the new stuff you gave it.

So something like:

```
  const cartRows = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
    this["cartData" + i] = cartData[i]


    const cartRow = `
        <tr class="cart-row">
            <td><a href="#" type="button" class="cart-remove-button"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
            <td><img src="${cartData[i][2]}" alt=""></td>
            <td>${cartData[i][0]}</td>
            <td class="cart-price">DZD ${cartData[i][1]}</td>
            <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1"></td>
            <td class="cart-sub-total">DZD ${cartData[i][1]}</td>
        </tr>`
      ;

    cartRows += cartRow;
  }

  cartItems.innerHTML = cartRows;
```